# Make a pdf with all references in a bibtex file

Tags: bibtex

I have a Bibtex file and I am trying to get a pdf file that contains all the references without any text. My intention is to use it as a list of relevant literature. Of course I can just use `\nocite{ev, ery, thing}` but then I always have to add items as something changes in the bibtex file. Is there an easy way to tell latex to list all the items from my bibtex file?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Or you can use `\nocite{*}`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
(La)TeX-related questions are better asked at [tex.se]. Your question has been flagged so that it gets migrated there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `biblist` package is what you want. From my own work (minimal setup)

```
\documentclass{article}

  \usepackage{biblist}

  \begin{document}

    \begin{center}
      {\Large \bf My Bibliography}
    \end{center}

    \bibliographystyle{IEEEtranS}
    \bibliography{IEEEabrv,mybib}

\end{document}
```

This creates its own document, you can pdf that.

Comment: Aren't you confusing `biblist` with `listbib`? The former in an *option*, while the latter is a package.

Comment: Nope. Just double checked this code. Works fine. From WinEdt ran `pdflatex.exe "prettyprint_bib.tex"` (file above) and got a pdf with my full bib listing. I'm using `textlive` 2013.

Comment: It's weird. It works here as well. But the documentation for `biblist` clearly states that it's an *option* , not a package. But then again, that documentation is from 1992.

Comment: LOL -- yeah, lots of latex stuff from the 1990s. I'm afraid I can't recall a reference to my code above. I can say my code is about 10 years old (c/p situation), that's when I was looking into this. I might have gotten it from Goossens et al.

Comment: I still have "The LaTeX Companion" on my bookshelf, although I haven't used it for a while. But it's in there alright.